# C Write String to Array

Tags: arrays, c

I have `Data.C`:

```
#include "Data.h"

char data_a[999][999];
```

`Data.h`:

```
#ifndef Data_h
#define Data_h

#include <stdio.h>
extern char data_a[999][999];
#endif /* Data_h */
```

And then `Main.c`:

```
#include "Data.h"

char *s;
...

printf("Write -%s- to -%d-\n",s,counter_a);
printf("BEFORE -%c-\n",data_a[counter_a][0]);
data_a[counter_a][0]=*s;
printf("AFTER  -%c-\n",data_a[counter_a][0]);
```

And when `Main.c` is run this is what is printed as an example:

```
Write - This is my sample string I want to save to the array at position 166 
- to -166-
BEFORE --
AFTER  - -
```

What I am trying to do is have `data_a[166][0]` be equal to the value of `s` which should be `"This is my sample string I want to save to the array at position 166"`. I know I have something not quite right, just need a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: The expression `*s` is *exactly* equal to `s[0]`. It's a single character. Which you already know since you use `%c` to print that single character. So you're writing the leading space in the string that `s` is pointing to. So I'm kind of confused as to what your problem might be? What is the output you *expect* to get?

Comment: For `data_a[166][0]` to *"be equal"* to a string of characters, `data` would have to be a three-dimensional array of `char` **OR** a two-dimensional array of `char *`.

Comment: You *probably* want `strcpy(data_a[counter_a], s)`.

Comment: You can also put the entire character arrays (not just pointers) in structs; *those* you can assign (including a deep array copy). Effectively the rudiment of a poor man's string class.

Comment: My expectation was that `data_a[166][0]` would be equal to `"This is my sample string I want to save to the array at position 166"`. So I think based on the comments my misunderstanding is that `data_a[166][0]` is actually a single character and not a string of characters?

Comment: Yes, because `char` is a single byte.

Comment: @ez4nick Indeed, it is a single character. That can be seen from the declaration: `char data_a[999][999];` decfines an object data_a that, indexed two times, has the type char. Indexing two times is what you do; a char is what you get. ;-).

Comment: If you index `data_a` one time only you get a one-dimensional array which is as close to a string as you can get in C. Alas, arrays are not assignable.

Comment: Appreciate all the suggestions, I was able to figure it out. The declaration I needed was `char *data_a[999][999];`.

Comment: The format specifier `-%s-` outputting `- This`... tells you that the string does not begin with a `T` as in `"This`... but rather a space character as in `" This`...  Your example lacks the details about how the string was set in the first place.  Regardless, `data_a[counter_a][0]=*s;` is just moving one char, not an entire string.

Comment: Are you sure [`char *data_a[999][999]`](https://cdecl.org/?q=char+*data_a%5B999%5D%5B999%5D) is what you want?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> data_a[counter_a][0]=*s;
> ```

This is saving the first character of `s` to the character at `data_a[counter_a][0]`. It doesn't affect any other character. Attempting to print this likely results in [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) unless `data_a[counter_a][1]` is `'\0'`. Without that null terminator `data_a[counter_a]` is a character array, but is *not* a string.

To copy the entirety of `s` into `data_a[counter_a]` you would use `strcpy` or more correctly `strncpy` as you know the bounds of `data_a[counter_a]`.

Comment: It might be a 1-character string left over from the static initialization of 0 at the second character, (but this isn't what the OP intended.)